# PHP Clear $_POST data. Prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html

Post/Redirect/Get - just don't get it(((
That one was working but after first refreshing wasn't able to log in again without deleting cache and cookie in browser.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['loaded'])
{
    // insert query here
}

$_SESSION['loaded'] = true;

?>
```

Here is my simple code:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  
  $userMail = $_POST["email"] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $password = $_POST["pass"] = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

 

  require_once('dbh.inc.php');
  require_once('functions.inc.php');

  
  } 
  else {
  header("location: AccessDenied.html");
  }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: @StackSlave Hi. I'm looking for some practical implementation of PRG or some other solutions of $_POST data clearing on back/forward/refresh basic on my code. I'm new in PHP and hoped to find some help here. Here is my problem, here is what i had tried, here is my code, any help appreciated. Just down vote? Well, I didn't saw any answer here...

Comment: @Sergiy - Is the idea that when someone submits a form, you do not want them to be able to refresh, back button, etc to submit it again by accident?

Comment: @Jesse Yes, exactly, thank you for understanding. 
How I understand POST/REDIRECT/GET is:
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) -> redirect to other page and then:  
if $_SESSION['login'] == true finaly output result. 
I don't know, does it make sense...maybe there are some better solutions.

Comment: Based on your current implementation, the simplest method is to ALSO use your header(location) redirect on success as well. That way, when a user hits the refresh button they are still on your success page, and if they hit the back button they go back to your login page.

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['loaded'])){ $_SESSION['loaded'] = true; / *only do your post now */ }`

Comment: @Sergiy -- Your note about having to clear browser cache makes me think of a logical problem with where the code that has that `header("location: AccessDenied.html");` is

Comment: Note that I really recommend that you check a value in a database instead of using the technique I've shown. What if the Client wants to visit your page again, during a different session?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reviewing your logic and re-reading your initial message I see the issue. This appears to be a logical issue.

Gonna take a crack at what I think you are trying to do:

**home.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    // If the session is not 'loaded', send them to login.php
    if (!$_SESSION['loaded'])
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
    
    // Todo: Business logic below, etc
```

**login.php** sends a post to something (lets say auth.php)

**auth.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once('dbh.inc.php');
    require_once('functions.inc.php');

    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        exit;
    }
  
    $userMail = $_POST['email'] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST['pass'] = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // Verify the user in some way
    if( $user_is_verified ) {

        // Set this session you used
        $_SESSION['loaded'] = true;

        // Send them back to the home page, now 'loaded' in the session
        header('Location: home.php');

    } else {

        // Send them back to the login page
        // Todo: Maybe also tell them why they failed, maybe in a session variable?
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
```

**Previous Answer:** Based on your replies in the comment section and the code that is visible, the simplest implementation would be to also use a `header('Location: some_success_url')` when the login is successful as well.

In this way, a refresh does nothing but refreshes the `some_success_url` page, and the back button just takes you back to the login page (or however your logic works when the user is already authenticated)

Comment: The Client could still hit back twice.

Comment: @Jesse +++. To log out I need to close/destroy session? And after refresh it will redirect to login.php?

Comment: If everything works on your server properly, then your session will still be active on refresh. Hitting the back button would send them back to the login page sure, but you could simply add logic to the login.php page to do things (like send them to home, or tell them they are already logged in and give them an option to logout). -- To destroy that session, use session_destroy() -- but ensure you start the session on that logout page as well with session_start() before doing so.

Comment: @Jesse Thank you so much to clarify all my questions and for your patience . Hope all is well and wish you all the best.

Comment: @Sergiy - glad to help, happy coding!